# How to get table name from POCO with Dapper Extensions mappings?

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-extensions

I have a table with name `MyTable` in my database. A POCO class `MyTablePoco` is created for that table.

Following is Mapping code of Dapper Extensions:

```
class MyTableMapper : ClassMapper<MyTablePoco>
{
    public MyTableMapper()
    {
        Table("MyTable");
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

Following is the code where I need table name from POCO class:

```
private string GetTableName<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).Name.Replace("Poco", "");
}
```

My convention for naming POCO classes is `TableName + "Poco"`. Based on this convention, my hack of replacing "Poco" from class name works great as shown in above example.

But, I would like to get the table name from mapping configurations instead. I think this will be more reliable as it avoids any string handling and assumptions about naming POCOs.

How can I get table name from POCO class with Dapper Extensions mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/pull/208) on GitHub. This is now merged in `master` branch. Hopefully this is now available out of the box and no need to download and modify the toolkit source code (as explained below) anymore. Note that I have not verified this as I am not using Dapper Extensions since few years.

---

Dapper Extensions project is open source; everyone knows that. I downloaded it from GitHub and modified it to meet my needs.

This feature is already present internally in library.

I added the following function in `DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions` `static` class:

```
public static string GetTableName<TPoco>() where TPoco : class
{
    return new SqlGeneratorImpl(_configuration).GetTableName(GetMap<TPoco>());
}
```

Here, `TPoco` is your POCO class.

Further, to get mapped column name, I added following function:

```
public static string GetColumnName<TPoco>(string propertyName) where TPoco : class
{
    return new SqlGeneratorImpl(_configuration).GetColumnName(GetMap<TPoco>(), propertyName, false);
}
```

Here, `TPoco` is your POCO class and `propertyName` is name of property of POCO class. One can easily get property name in Framework 4.5 or above as:

```
nameof(myPocoInstance.MyProperty)
```